como mandar un ping de bytes especifico y setear el don`t fragment para que no se fragmente en terminal linux debian?
hola que tal tengo unos ejercicios que me dice de mandar cierta cantidad de bytes pero que no se fragmente.
utilizo el ping -s bytes destino para los mandar 1400 bytes y 900 bytes.
cuando quise mandar los 1400 me aparecio mtu=1000, y al mandar los 900 me aparecio mtu=800.
y en wireshark se ve que se fragmento todo.
me pregunta es si se podria setear el don't fragment desde la terminal.
les dejo los ejercicios:
b. Ejecutar comando ping de manera de enviar un datagrama IP al destino con 1400 bytes de
longitud total y sin permitir que se realice fragmentación.
c. Ejecutar comando ping de manera de enviar un datagrama IP al destino con 900 bytes de
longitud total y sin permitir que se realice fragmentación.
d. Ejecutar comando ping de manera de enviar un datagrama IP al destino con 600 bytes de
longitud total y sin permitir que se realice fragmentación

¿ping -M do -s 1392 <ip> / ping -M probe -s 1392 <ip>?

Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque la pregunta tiene estilo "hazme la tarea"

en realidad las preguntas de la tarea vienen despues de hacer esto.
